# Android WebView loadUrl after postUrl

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem using loadUrl after postUrl.
First I use postUrl to login to a website and after that I want to load another page from the same website with loadUrl. But after using loadUrl Im asked again to login.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to handle `cookie` with `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the COOKIE returned by the POST request (i.e., the login request). Then, whenever you send a GET request, you need to pass along the cookie so the sever knows you've already logged in.